# Mongodb design advice - todo list

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating a kind of project management app which consists of 'jobs' and 'entities' (or tasks) within those jobs. As part of it I'm creating a todo list which should be unique to each user and I'm wondering what the best design is for the database?

Entities exist in their own collection and are related to jobs through a jobId field.

My initial thought was to structure it like:

```
Entity 
    Todos[]
         User1
               Todo1
               Todo2
               ...
         User2
         ...
```

I also have a users collection so would it better to store the todos there like:

```
User 
     Todos[]
           Entity
                Todo1 
                Todo2
                ...
```

Or some other method?? I think updating and deleting todos will be quite tricky..

**Update**

Option 3 - I could remove the user array and store the user on each todo object, like:

```
Entity
     Todos[]
           Todo{
                 User: John
                 Text: some todo
                 Done: false
```

Then filter all todos by a specific user. I will get some duplicate data (the user) but I don't think that's so bad..

Also when updating/deleting a todo is it safe to match it based on the text field or do I need to store a unique id on each todo?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 may well worth reading

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your initial thought is the best of the two.  In it, the User is referenced.  In the second it looks like a user document with the todos in it.  I think that is a little too much coupling, the first method being better decomposed and easier to modify/maintain as the reasons dictate in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how I would then query and edit the todo? I was struggling with it today since it's within two arrays..